# In which namespace is the DelegateCommand in?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, delegatecommand

I am trying to work out an example from ".NET Domain Driven Design with C#", which contains a code example where you can see declared some attributes of type `DelegateCommand`.

Now, I've tried googling it up, but I can't find its reference anywhere on MSDN (actually, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126.aspx) article, but not `DelegateCommand`'s article itself).

Is the `DelegateCommand` something that's part of `WPF` or is it just something created in the book?

If it's part of WPF (or any other MS product), in which assembly/namespace is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DelegateCommand is not (yet) part of the standard library (BCL).

It is part of WPF command-binding for MVVM.

Until we get an 'official' MVVM template in VS, all the MVVM examples/toolkits define it somewhere themselves. Not always with the same name or in the same place.

Answer (score 10):

If you use MS Prism,downlaod the lib,  add the reference to the project, then you have

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands; // for DelegateCommand & RaisePropertyChanged
```

Comment: If you want to get Prism, make sure NuGet is installed, open the package Manager Console and enter `Install-Package prism`.

Answer (score 3):

`DelegateCommands` is a custom implementation of `ICommand`. `DelegateCommand` was introduced(correct me if I am wrong) in prism(Composite Application framework) - http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

You can use that or you can implement your own as done here -

https://web.archive.org/web/20101120214610/http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html

Answer (score 2):

I've found it called `RelayCommand` (I think that's the original name, to be honest).  Please see here:

> [MVVM Routed and Relay Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650010/mvvm-routed-and-relay-command)
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051

Hope that helps!

Comment: From the MSDN article -

"RelayCommand is a simplified variation of the DelegateCommand found in the Microsoft Composite Application Library."